# Why the list returned by a one column query can't be iterated with an Object array?

Tags: hibernate, object

Consider the below code:

```
Query query1 = session.createQuery("select c.marks from StudentEntity c");
            List<Object[]> l = query1.list();
            for (Object[] object : l) 
            {
                System.out.print(object[0]);
                System.out.println("______________");
            }
```

It throws a ClassCast Exception as follows:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

I know what this Exception means:
Integer can't be converted to 1-d Object array

Instead of Object array list, if I use Object type list to iterate over the returned list from query, it gives me the desired output as follows:

```
List<Object[]> l = query1.list();
            for (Object object : l) 
            {
                System.out.print(object);
                System.out.println("______________");
            }

78______________
65______________
77______________
```

I understand that there is only one attribute in the list returned by the query. For more than 1 column, I have to go for Object array.

But my question is that why the list returning 1 column can't be iterated with an Object array of size 1 (as in the 1st code snippet .i.e. object[0]) ?

Is it compulsory that the resulting list should contain more than 1 column to be eligible to be iterated with Object array class ?

Is it because Integer class extends Object class and not Object array class and Object array comes into picture only when query returns more than one columns since the list returning 2 columns together can't be retrieved from Object only?

Is there any reference in Java docs about when one should use Object array and when Object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query selecting a single field of type `Foo` (`Integer`, in your case), will return a `List<Foo>` (i.e. a `List<Integer>` in your case).

A query selecting several fields, of types `Foo` and `Bar`for example, will return a `List<Object[]>`. Each object array will contain as many elements as fields in the select clause, in the same order. So, in this example, it will contain a Foo and a Bar.

That's what the JPA specification specifies, and it seems pretty natural to me: wrapping single fields into an Object would be unnecessary, would consume memory, and would be cumbersome to use since you would have to unwrap the object from the array containing it.

Comment: So is it by design that a single object can't be put in Object array ? It should be minimum 2 columns. Any references ?

Comment: Read my answer. It tells you exactly the inverse: *A query selecting a single field of type Foo (Integer, in your case), will return a List<Foo> (i.e. a List<Integer> in your case).* How do you conclude, from that sentence, that it would return a `List<Object[]>` containing object arrays of size 1? You get a ClassCastException precisely because the returned list doesn't (and shouldn't) contain Object[]. It contains (and should contain) Integers.

Comment: But integer is also an Object. And Object array is a group of Objects. So why can I not use Object array in this case ? This is my Question. I already know that it will return me list of Integer. But why can I not use Object array of size 1 in this case ? Please clarify .

Comment: An Integer is an `Object`. But it's not an `Object[]`. `Object[]` means "array of Objects". And an Integer is not an array of Objects. If you ask an egg to your grocer, and the grocer gives you just that: an egg, you can't pretend you have a box containing one egg in your hands. You don't. All you have is one egg. Trying to pretend the egg is a box containing one egg won't lead you anywhere. You won't be able to open the box, because you don't have one.

Comment: I understood your point. Thanks for trying to make me understand that point. I tried this: List<Object[]>list  = new ArrayList<Object[]>(); Then I tried this:Object[] object = new Object[5]; Object object1  = new Object();      But I could add only the object array into the list not the normal object. Because the list is of Object array not of object. That is what happening in my case also. I understood it with your example.